# Gulp task to web deploy from Visual Studio

Tags: msbuild, gulp, webdeploy

I have not found a concrete example on how to do the publishing via a Gulp Task. Anyone has an idea?

This is how i'm trying at the moment.

```
gulp.task("Deploy-To-Azure", function() {
var targets = ["Build"];
console.log("Publishing to Azure");
return gulp.src(["./src/Feature/Accounts/code"])
.pipe(foreach(function (stream, file) {
    return stream
      .pipe(debug({ title: "Building project:" }))
      .pipe(msbuild({
          targets: targets,
          configuration: "Azure",
          logCommand: false,
          verbosity: "verbose",
          stdout: true,
          errorOnFail: true,
          maxcpucount: 0,
          toolsVersion: 14.0,
          properties: {
              DeployOnBuild: "true",
              DeployDefaultTarget: "Web Deploy",
              WebPublishMethod: "FileSystem",
              DeleteExistingFiles: "false",
              _FindDependencies: "false",
              Configuration: "Release"
          }
      }))
    .pipe(debug({title: "Finished building project"}));
}));
```

});

But it looks like the project is built but not deployed. I think my properties are not complete. Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to use those same MSBuild properties from the commandline and received the following error:

```
>c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPub
lishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=false /p:DeployDefaultTarget="Web Deploy"
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.P
ublishing.targets(4449,11): error MSB4057: The target "Web Deploy" does not exi
st in the project. [c:\users\me\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\w
ebapplication12\WebApplication12.csproj]
```

Unless you've created a custom MSBuild Target named "Web Deploy".  This won't work.

When I remove the `/p:DeployDefaultTarget="Web Deploy"` property a WebDeploy package is created in the `/obj/[configuration]/Package` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try DeployDefaultTarget: "WebPublish"